# Combine rows within level of multi-level dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I combined two dataframes in the following way:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Farm ID": ["1", "2", "2", "3", "3"],
        "Crop": ["Type A", "Type A", "Type B", "Type A", "Type B"],
        "Area": [8, 4, 2, 3, 5],
        "Diesel": [101, 215, 3, 0.6, 42],
        "Gas": [15, 35, 61, 95, 13]
    }
)
df1 = df1.set_index(['Farm ID', 'Crop'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": ["Area", "Diesel", "Gas"],
        "GHG": [690, 8.5, 13],
        "LU": [2.2, 0.3, 1.1],
    }
)
df2 = df2.set_index('Name')

s = df1.stack()
out = df2.reindex(s.index.get_level_values(2)).mul(s.values,axis=0)
out.index = s.index
out = out.rename_axis(['Farm ID','Crop', 'Type'])
```

So it now looks like this:

```
                        GHG     LU
Farm ID Crop    Type        
1       Type A  Area    5520.0  17.60
                Diesel  858.5   30.30
                Gas     195.0   16.50
2       Type A  Area    2760.0  8.80
                Diesel  1827.5  64.50
                Gas     455.0   38.50
        Type B  Area    1380.0  4.40
                Diesel  25.5    0.90
                Gas     793.0   67.10
3       Type A  Area    2070.0  6.60
                Diesel  5.1     0.18
                Gas     1235.0  104.50
        Type B  Area    3450.0  11.00
                Diesel  357.0   12.60
                Gas     169.0   14.30
```

I now want to sum in each of the groups *Fuel=Diesel+Gas*. So for each *Farm ID* and *Crop Type* I want to have in the end the Types *Area* and *Fuel*
In a 1-dim dataframe, I would create the new row as `df.loc['Fuel'] = df.loc['Diesel'] + df.loc['Gas']` but this doesn't work here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, reset the index of your dataframe then replace `Diesel` and `Gas` names by `Fuel` on `Type` column, then `groupby` again and `sum`:

```
d = {'Diesel': 'Fuel', 'Gas': 'Fuel'}
out = out.reset_index().replace({'Type': d}).groupby(['Farm ID', 'Crop', 'Type']).sum()
print(out)

# Output:
                        GHG      LU
Farm ID Crop   Type                
1       Type A Area  5520.0   17.60
               Fuel  1053.5   46.80
2       Type A Area  2760.0    8.80
               Fuel  2282.5  103.00
        Type B Area  1380.0    4.40
               Fuel   818.5   68.00
3       Type A Area  2070.0    6.60
               Fuel  1240.1  104.68
        Type B Area  3450.0   11.00
               Fuel   526.0   26.90
```